# Pause a running function pressing a button

Tags: c, function, while-loop, gtk2

I have a gtk2+ code in which I have a running button and a stopping one. I want that the stop button pause the RUN function (not to leave it) in a specific point until run button is pressed again, continuing in the same point.

The problem is that while loops block any kind of interaction with program interfaces and freezes.

```
void STOP(GtkWidget *widget, GObject *context_object_stop) 
{
  stop=1; 
}

void RUN(GtkWidget *widget, GObject *context_object_run) 
{

  GtkEntry *buffer= g_object_get_data (context_object_run, "buffer");
  GtkTextIter iter; 
  GtkTextMark *marker; 
  marker = gtk_text_buffer_get_insert(buffer);
  gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_mark(buffer, &iter, marker);

  stop=0;
  int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<5000000; i=i+1)
    {
     while (stop==1)
     {
       //here is my problem
     }
     gchar * stuff = g_strdup_printf("%d""\n", i);
     gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &iter, stuff, -1);
     g_free(stuff);
     while (gtk_events_pending())
     gtk_main_iteration();
     gtk_text_view_scroll_mark_onscreen(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(wins), marker);
    }

}
```

Any ideas to approach the solution?

---

EDIT; An approach of multithreading that does not stop running the main function:

```
  stop=0;
  int i=0;
  pthread_t th1;

    for (i=0; i<5000000; i=i+1)
    {
     void *StopRun(void *arg)
     {
     while (stop==1)
     {
       //here is my problem
     }
     }
     if (stop==1)
     {
     pthread_create(&th1, NULL, (void*)StopRun, NULL);
     }
     gchar * stuff = g_strdup_printf("%d""\n", i);
     gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &iter, stuff, -1);
     g_free(stuff);
     while (gtk_events_pending())
     gtk_main_iteration();
     gtk_text_view_scroll_mark_onscreen(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(wins), marker);
    }
```

Comment: you should run your GUI in a different thread, so it won't get blocked by your loops

Comment: generally, capital letters are used for macros/defines, not function names.

Comment: What do you mean with a different thread, @JohnDoe2991 ?

Comment: You can avoid locking your application, if you start a new thread for every time consuming operation, for example your loops. Your loop will be executed in Thread 1 while in Thread 0 your GUI is still running and not locked. An example how to use threads with the boost library is described [here](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.thread)
If you don't know what a thread is, then [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm) are more information.

Comment: The process that executes on run button is from owner or external thread?

Comment: Its from owner @Joel. I was looking this topic during this day and the most "obvious" method for doing that is taking different threads as JohnDoe2991 said. But...there is other kind of method to avoid the multi-thread technique? I can't figure out anything.

Comment: I make an edit with an approach, but something fails with threads.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the documentation and examples of [gtk_events_pending](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-events-pending). It says:

> This can be used to update the UI and invoke timeouts etc. while doing some time intensive computation.